# Bootstrap Gallery with same image size

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'd like to make a gallery with Laravel and Boostrap and actually, I'm getting a trouble.
First, here is my code :

```
            @foreach($files as $file)
            @if($file->getFilename() !== "cover.jpg")
                <div  class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 gallery-container">
                    <a href="{{url($urldirectory.$file->getFilename())}}">
                        <img src="{{url($urldirectory.$file->getFilename())}}" class="img-responsive thumb"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

And if I put image with different size whether in portrait or landscape, I'm getting a difference on the height size. And I've a great space between each row.

My currently CSS is :

```
.gallery-container{
    height: 300px;
}
```

Anyone see what I've missed here ?

Answer (score 0):

Including me from your question understood the image greater than maximum height.

You can try to add this to your css:

```
.thumb {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

This will set the max height for the images. If you want to set also the max width you can add the follow css:

```
.thumb {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: So, Iv'e tried this but not working because vertical picture took 2 row and horizontals one don't have the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set height of image using Div.
Give height and width to **img** tag  and remove **gallery-container** class .

You code should look like this

```
@foreach($files as $file)
            @if($file->getFilename() !== "cover.jpg")
                <div  class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                    <a href="{{url($urldirectory.$file->getFilename())}}">
                        <img src="{{url($urldirectory.$file->getFilename())}}" class="img-responsive thumb" width="304" height="300"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks but this solution not works because verticale image took 2 row even if it have the same height of 2 row and horizontal pictures don't have the same height too when their size is diffrent.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?

http://leastjs.com/

from this all you have to do is:

```
<section id="least">
     <div class="least-preview"></div>
     <ul class="least-gallery">
     @if(isset($images))
         @foreach($images as $img)
             <li>
                <a href="{{asset($img->source)}}" title="View" data-subtitle="{{$img->title}}" data-caption="<p>{{$img->caption}}</p><br>
                    <img src="{{asset($img->source)}}" alt="" />
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    @endif
 </ul>
 </section>
```

and the script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.least-gallery').least();
    });
</script>
```

P.S.: You also get cool effects like image preview and other stuff

only css solution

```
.gallery-container li {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.gallery-container li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
}
.gallery-container li a img {
  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Mhhhh i Keep this solution in minde but I'm sure there is a way to do it only on CSS ^^

Comment: @AragornD7 try the css only part

Answer (score 0):

I think you should manipulate the size of image from server-side. I used https://github.com/Intervention/image. Then I used [URL based image manipulation](http://image.intervention.io/use/url).

Comment: I don't want to resize the picture on the web server. I just want a display with the same size as responsive pictures. But thanks anyway for your purpose :)